# adding a filter to my ng-options returns no set?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object i properly iterate over:

```
<select ng-options="value.name for (key,value) in ctrl.userList"></select>
```

I wanted to add a filter on the object, such as:

```
|filter:value.superior!=null
```

which would only show users without any current assigned superior.

It seems that right now, it shows none, but should show 1.  Is there something I am missing when applying a filter?

Full example I have been working with:

```
<select ng-options="value.name for (key,value) in ctrl.userList | filter: value.superior!=null"></select>
```

The sample i am iterating over is:

```
Var obj = {
  0: {name:"test", superior:null},
  1: {name:"test 2", superior:0}
};
```

Sample Angular Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p4Lj11on/

Comment: removed a tag, because this is not angular 2.

Comment: Could you provide an example that we can run? Like a runnable snippet or jFiddle

Comment: Let me see if i can get a fiddle up and running or something to make it easy

Comment: @Hack-R added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per angular doc, first argument to filter must be array. You are passing object. If userList is an array it will work properly(try this). You can solve this by using custom filter.

```
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(obj, prop, value) {
    var result = {};
    for(key in obj) {
      if(obj[key][prop] !== value)
       result[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return result;
  };
});
```

markup:

```
|myfilter: 'superior' : null
```

Comment: So, how would I resolve this issue?  Can you add some code?  `app.filter("myFilter", function(){});` which would solve my issue instead of just pointing me to docs?  I have been looking into this and cant really find a sample which will solve this for me.

Comment: @just confirming:   The markup would look like:  `|myFilter:value`

Comment: just `| myfilter`

Comment: is there a way to make this dynamic?  Maybe to accept any list of objects, and then pass in any conditional, such as an arbitrary property and an expected value?

Comment: I say this because creating a js file of various filters based on the passed in object is kind of tedious, and would rather like to make it work under a more general case

Comment: Yes, you can pass an arbitrary property and an expected value but first parameter will always be object on which filter applied.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd add this answer to help if you ever decide to change to an array of objects, and to help anyone else having this issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cm8xoH5oVewTxce98L47?p=preview

HTML Element;

`<select ng-model="test" ng-options="value.name for (key,value) in obj | filter:{superior: ''}"></select>`

Angular array;

```
 $scope.obj = [
    {
      name: "test",
      superior: null
    },
    {
      name: "test2",
      superior: 0
    }];
```